# Rotation matrix to invert Z-axis

Tags: python, matlab, 3d

I am working with some 3D data and the Z-axis is not in the correct orientation. I can always use z = -z and fix it. But, is there a rotation operation that does the same job?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to me this should just be the identity matrix with one of the diagonal elements negated...

Comment: For the data array, flip(DATA,3), for plotting, set(gca(),'ZDir','reverse').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By negating the `z` axis, the coordinate system is no longer dextral (i.e., it doesn't follow the right-hand rule). A rotation matrix preserves the right-dexterity, and a valid rotation can be obtained by using `rotationVectorToMatrix(rotationVector)` where `rotationVector` can be `[pi; 0; 0]`.

If you don't care about the dexterity of the system, then the answers by [beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377097/beaker) and [wwweagle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321247/wwweagle) in the comments should do the job.

Comment: Okay, so negate *two* diagonal elements.